# Mysql join multiple periodes to multiple office

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I would like to make a join or something else to be able to get this result.

Here is the result I want, each office_id must have 13 periodes.

```
Office_id | periode | nb |
1         |    1    |  6 |
1         |    2    |  9 |
1         |    3    |  11|
1         |    4    |  1 |
1         |    5    |  7 |
1         |    6    |  11|
1         |    7    |  11|
1         |    8    |  9 |
1         |    9    |  6 |
1         |   10    |  1 |
1         |   11    |  8 |
1         |   12    |  3 |
1         |   13    |  0 |
2         |    1    |  1 |
2         |    2    |  0 |
2         |    3    |  2 |
2         |    4    |  1 |
2         |    5    |  0 |
2         |    6    |  0 |
2         |    7    |  2 |
2         |    8    |  0 |
2         |    9    |  0 |
2         |   10    |  0 |
2         |   11    |  0 |
2         |   12    |  0 |
2         |   13    |  0 |
3         |    1    |  1 |
3         |    2    |  3 |
3         |    3    |  2 |
3         |    4    |  4 |
3         |    5    |  4 |
3         |    6    |  2 |
3         |    7    |  0 |
3         |    8    |  1 |
3         |    9    |  3 |
3         |   10    |  0 |
3         |   11    |  0 |
3         |   12    |  0 |
3         |   13    |  0 |
```

From

table_name: temp

```
office_id | Periode | nb |
1         |   1     | 6  |
1         |   2     | 9  |
1         |   3     | 11 |
1         |   4     | 1  |
1         |   5     | 7  |
1         |   6     | 11 |
1         |   7     | 11 |
1         |   8     | 9  |
1         |   9     | 6  |
1         |  10     | 1  |
1         |  11     | 8  |
1         |  12     | 3  |
2         |   1     | 1  |
2         |   3     | 2  |
2         |   4     | 1  |
2         |   7     | 2  |
3         |   1     | 1  |
3         |   2     | 3  |
3         |   3     | 2  |
3         |   4     | 4  |
3         |   5     | 4  |
3         |   6     | 2  |
3         |   8     | 1  |
3         |   9     | 3  |
```

and

table_name: Periodes

```
id | year | periode
1   2017    1
2   2017    2
3   2017    3
4   2017    4
5   2017    5
6   2017    6
7   2017    7
8   2017    8
9   2017    9
10  2017    10
11  2017    11
12  2017    12
13  2017    13
```

How can I do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Sample data is great. However, perhaps you could use 3 instead of 13 periods here - just to the problem easier to get.

Comment: just a suggestion .. left join

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the data:

```
select o.office_id, p.periode, coalesce(t.nb, 0) as nb
from (select distinct office_id from t) o cross join
     periodes p left join
     t
     on t.office_id = o.office_id and t.periode = p.periode
where p.year = 2017
order by o.office_id, p.periode;
```